# Can’t use sudo after umount —all

Tags: linux, mount, sudo, fstab

I tried to unmount all of my fstab mounts by using:

```
sudo umount --all
```

Right after that i tried to remount everything by using:

```
sudo mount -a
```

But got this error:

> sudo: effective uid is not 0, is /usr/bin/sudo on a file system with the ‘nosuid’ options set or an NFS file system without root privileges?

Now sudo doesn’t work at all even for simple commands. How could I fix this?

Comment: Boot from USB and fix it?

Answer (score 2):

The error message indicates that the mount containing `/usr/bin/sudo` (i.e. `/usr/bin/` or `/usr/` or even just `/`) is mounted with the `nosuid` option. But without the effective [`suid` bit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid) `sudo` is unable to change the effective user.

So what probably happened is that `umount --all` unmounted `/usr/bin` or `/usr/`. *Now* running `sudo` will execute the binary file `/usr/bin/sudo` which is placed on the filesystem/mount that was previously covered/overlayed by the *now unmounted* filesystem at `/usr/bin`*.

If all you did was `sudo umount --all` a simple reboot should fix the problem since all configured mounts should be mounted automatically again.

If you can not/do not want to reboot you'll need some other way to execute `mount -a` as root:

- try logging in as root directly
- try using [`su`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/su) instead

---

*the filesystem previously mounted at `/usr/bin/` may also be the same device but remounted with different options